# C# get the the type Generic<T> given T

Tags: c#, generics, types

I have a generic class in C#, like this:

```
   public class GenericClass<T> { ... }
```

Now, I have the `Type` object for an object, and would like to, through reflection or otherwise, to get the `Type` object for `GenericClass<T>` where T corresponds to that Type object I have my object.

Like this:

```
   Type requiredT = myobject.GetType();
   Type wantedType = typeof(GenericClass<requiredT>);
```

Obviously this syntax doesn't work, but how do I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
Type requiredT = ...
Type genericType = typeof(GenericClass<>);
Type wantedType = genericType.MakeGenericType(requiredT);
```

This will give you the `GenericClass<T>` Type object, where T corresponds to your `requiredT`.

You can then construct an instance using `Activator`, like this:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(wantedType, new Object[] { ...params });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Type requiredT = myobject.GetType();
Type genericType = typeof(GenericClass<>);
Type wantedType = genericType.MakeGenericType(requiredT);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Type wantedType = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(requiredT);
```