# Getting All Generic Types in C# from an Assembly

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to get a list of generic types of a library to filter them for certain traits.
I'm trying to test if an interface implementation implements the interface contract correctly, and try to list all types that inherit from that interface, but the interface contains a generic parameter.

The issue that I think this approach has is that if a test/assembly does not generate an instance of the generic type, it will not contain a reference to that type.

I have already found:

- this does not give me the posibility to look for types, unless I know the type: [C# get the the type Generic<T> given T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537466/c-sharp-get-the-the-type-generict-given-t)
- getting all types from an assembly does not include generic types, I made a test case below that proves this fact.

```
    public class MyClass<T>
    {
        public T t { get; set; }

        public MyClass(T t)
        {
            this.t = t;
        }
    }

    public class SimpleTest
    {

        [Fact]
        public void TestCreateMyClass()
        {
            var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                 .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                                 .Where(p => p.GetType().FullName.Contains("MyClass")).ToArray();
            Assert.NotEmpty(types); // fails
        }
    }
```

My current workaround for this is to explicitly list all classes of that type to make a check, but I would prefer some automated way as people are expected to extend this functionality and I want them to be automatically tested.

Comment: You've got a logic error. Change `p.GetType().FullName` to `p.FullName`.

Comment: Are you trying to find all the types that derive from your base class?

Comment: @DavidG yes precisely. it's an interface though not a base class.

Comment: So like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645430/get-all-types-implementing-specific-open-generic-type

Comment: @DavidG yes precisely like this, the real issue seems to be how I create the assembly, gurus answer works for me. if I specify the assembly like he does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your type has an interface which is generic (`IsGenericType`) and which `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` is equal to your generic type interface:

```
interface IGeneric<T> { }

public class MyClass<T> : IGeneric<T> { }

public class MyClassConcrete : IGeneric<int> { }

var assembly = typeof(IGeneric<>).Assembly; // get assembly somehow

var types = assembly.GetTypes()
    .Where(t => !t.IsInterface)
    .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && typeof(IGeneric<>) == i.GetGenericTypeDefinition()));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", types)); // prints MyClass`1[T], MyClassConcrete
```